# Can LiDaR be used for volume measurement?

Tags: point-cloud

I need to measure volume with LiDaRs. However, they seem to only capture the surface of an object. More precisely, the surface that is seen by the sensor. Therefore, the cloud point data that it generates can't know the object's dimensions.

I've seen a video of where they measure stockpiles of sand. However, I guess the image is taken from above. This is a specific case where it's possible, because the LiDaR gives the distance to the top of the 'cone' of sand, and also the distance to the ground, so we can use simple math to estimate.

But in general, it can't be done. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Check out [this post over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970803/algorithm-for-calculating-the-volume-of-the-part-of-point-cloud). It has some information that may be useful.

Comment: If you can't work out the volume using the surface, does that mean if I give you a cube, you wouldn't be able to know its volume without cutting it up?

Comment: I think this question would need a bit more detail to receive a useful answer. In general. Yes, it is possible. You can always calculate the volume of a solid. Is it meaningful? It depends on the application. If you assume that the pile of sand is symmetrical, then all you need is enough points off of its surface to achieve a good fit to a cone. Do you think you could add a bit more detail about what you are dealing with?